# "jQuery Not Defined" Error When Connecting to PayPal

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I have been looking all over Google for hours now and am very confused. Everyone has a different answer, and most don't explain where to put the code snippet that they post.

I am attempting to create a new blog and web store with a self-hosted WordPress site. The site is running on a machine running the latest version of Ubuntu Server and apache2. I am using the plugin "WP Simple PayPal Shopping Cart" to create a way for users to checkout. On the checkout page, attempting to checkout with PayPal Express will cause the "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" error, seemingly due to a JavaScript file on PayPal's servers.

I am not sure how to fix this. I am aware that jQuery should be loaded before anything attempts to run it, but I have no idea how to do that, or if it's already correct and that isn't the issue at all. I also saw that some speed boosting plugins could cause the issue but I have not installed any of them. Any help would be appreciated.

The site is **broketrainenthusiast.com** but to see the issue you'll need to add this fake item to your cart at **broketrainenthusiast.com/example/** and then initiate a purchase by clicking the PayPal button on broketrainenthusiast.com/cart/ (don't worry. it's in Sandbox mode).

As I said, any help with this would be appreciated, as this error prevents any successful transaction from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the WordPress 5.5 update which has removed jQuery. I'd suggest trying the [Enable jQuery Migrate Helper plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/).

Comment: I just tried and there’s no change. This issue persisted before 5.5, however it’s possible that the developers will update it to not require jQuery now. But I suppose it’s PayPal not the plugin.